# MarkLogic 9 permission issue on REST endpoint?

Tags: rest, permissions, marklogic

I have a function in a module for writing a user profile object.

```
// create scc user
function createUserProfile(userObj) {
// create user
var uri = fn.concat('/users/',userObj.id,'.json');
var data = {uri : uri, userName : userObj.userName, doc : userObj };
// we add the user as owner of this insert so he/she will own the doc
var options = {"isolation" : "different-transaction"}; //,"userId" : 
xdmp.user(userObj.userName)};
xdmp.eval('declareUpdate(); 
xdmp.documentInsert(uri, doc,[xdmp.permission(userName,"read"),xdmp.permission(userName,"update")]); 
xdmp.documentAddCollections(uri,"sccss-users")',
                            data,options);
return uri
};
```

Now if I first create the object the function works, but if I update the object using the same function it works from the console but not from a REST client?

Is there an issue with permissions? I have tried adding

```
    var options = {"isolation" : "different-transaction","userId" : xdmp.user(userObj.userName)};
```

works again in console but not solved my issue.

Actually the REST client does not get an answer back from the endpoint, after a while de database times out, see the log.

The MarkLogic serverlog:

```
2018-01-25 21:28:13.597 Info: {"firstName":"Hugo", "lastName":"Koopmans", "userName":"xxxxxx", "email":"xxx@xxx.com", "password":"xxxxx", "activationCode":"4db600e771f85073a03ed16371ba39ad3b408852", "active":false, "id":"xxxxxx", "devices":["xxxxxxx"]}
2018-01-25 21:29:47.559 Notice: SVC-CANCELED: xdmp.documentInsert("/users/952187962xx.json", ObjectNode({"firstName":"Hugo", "lastName":"Koopmans", "userName":"xxxxx", "email":"...", ...}), Sequence({...XDMP-CANCELED: Canceled request "/v1/users/passwordreset"..., {...XDMP-CANCELED: Canceled request "/v1/users/passwordreset"...)) -- Canceled
2018-01-25 21:29:47.559 Notice:+in xdmp:eval("declareUpdate(); xdmp.documentInsert(uri, doc,[xdmp.permission(u...", {uri:"/users/952187962xxxxx.json", userName:"xxxxx", doc:{firstName:"Hugo", lastName:"Koopmans", userName:"xxxxx", ...}}, {isolation:"different-transaction", userId:"9521879xxxx"}) [javascript]
2018-01-25 21:29:47.559 Notice:+in /v1/users.sjs [javascript]
2018-01-25 21:29:47.559 Notice:+in /v1/users.sjs [javascript]
2018-01-25 21:29:48.535 Notice: XDMP-CANCELED: Canceled request "/MarkLogic/rest-api/error-handler.xqy"
2018-01-25 21:29:48.535 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/manage/endpoints/databases/partitions/partitions.xqy, at 184:9, in pa:get-partition() [1.0-ml]
2018-01-25 21:29:48.535 Notice: XDMP-CANCELED: Canceled request "/MarkLogic/rest-api/error-handler.xqy"
2018-01-25 21:29:48.535 Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/error-handler.xqy [1.0-ml]
```

Questions:
- The permissions 'read' an 'update' should do the trick here also for actually updating a document with xdmp.documentInsert()
- Why does the function work if run from the console (as admin but with userId set as explained above.

Comment: Admin user circumvents lots of security and permissions. This makes troubleshooting issues like this more difficult when mixing Admin into the investigation. Can you add a few more items for clarification:(1)When exactly are you using admin and when are you using another user? Some parts are not clear above. (2) have you tried using the user from query console and removing admin altogether -helps isolate where things are truly going wrong. (3) please provide the user and role and a confirmation from the document permissions of what is assigned to the document.

Comment: Hugo, you only share a part of your code. I'm suspecting you are trying to check if a user profile exists before invoking that function, but keep in mind that will create a uri lock, even if the doc doesn't exist. You then do an eval in a different transaction, which is going to wait indefinitely for the uri lock to get released. Do you really need the eval?

Comment: PS: you can specify collections with xdmp.documentInsert, no need for the extra xdmp.documentAddCollections call..

Comment: thx Geert, indeed the uri lock, and also true : I did not need the eval.

Comment: for PUT you need rest-write, for GET rest-read